# when using wait(), cannot read pipe?

Tags: c, pipe, wait

Here is a small piece of code, the parent process write pipe and child read pipe, everything works fine before I add 'wait()' in parent process. I think it should be no difference, but it just stucks when I input. I'm quite new to system programming. Anyone can help with this?

```
int main() {
      char* msg = malloc(sizeof(100));
      int fd[2];
      pipe(fd);
      int status;


if (fork()!=0){
    close(fd[0]);
    dup2(fd[1],1);
    scanf("%s",msg);
    puts(msg);
    wait(&status);
}
else {
    char* buf = malloc(sizeof(100));
    close(fd[1]);
    dup2(fd[0],0);
    scanf("%s",buf);
    puts(buf);
}
return 0;}
```

Comment: what if fork returns -1? proper error handling: it's what's for dinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to flush `stdout` before calling `wait()`.

Your program was working before without the `wait()` since an implicit flush was done when the parent process exit.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close `fd[1]` after the `dup2` call in the parent. Also, you need to write some character that will cause `scanf` to realize it has read the end of the string. Closing stdout after calling `puts` would be one way.

Answer (score 0):

You should read a good book on [advanced unix programming](http://basepath.com/aup/), learn to use multiplexing calls like [poll(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html) (or `select`, or `pselect`, or `ppoll`), possibly learn to use [SIGCHLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGCHLD). Be careful, a [signal](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html) handler can call only a very limited set of functions (the async-safe one) and should often set a `volatile sig_atomic_t`  variable.